# How can I bundle the minimum set of dependencies to make my app standalone?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to get my app ready for shipping and I would like to make it standalone and include all dependencies so users don't have to download anything extra.

How can I identify the *minimum* required functions and classes my project depends on and extract those to a separate folder instead of including whole packages?

Including each package in full that my project depends on gives me 450 mb of files which is way too large because 95% of those files aren't even being used.

I know this is pretty similar to what pyinstaller does, but I don't want a .exe file. I just want the minimum dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently pyinstaller has a noarchive option which does exactly that.